I think I'm experiencing gender discrimination
My position as the only female that was trained and was supposed to start a lead tech / repair position was taken away.
My lead tech role matches the males I work with and I have been denied a raise for being at the top of the scale but raises have been given to  the males.
When a repair position opened and I applied the manager, HR rep asked questions different from the other interviews. I was told it was a bad interview but the manager sat inappropriately and the HR person later lied and defended the interview as not perfect.
I was the only lead tech to not receive a raise with the others at that time all the same day. I was next in line ro begin repair and instead they hired back an ex employee as manager and I was told now I have to wait a year.
I have no one to speak with , every day im getting more down on myself and am stuck doing a job that isn't the job I agreed to or was told I was going to have. I should be making 30 an hour .
The open positions for repair were given to 2 less skilled and younger men.
What can I do ?

If you think this is gender discrimination you should contact a local labor lawyer. Laws, culture, and rules around this vary greatly around the globe, so adding a country tag would be extremely helpful

What you can do is: First, tell your management that this isn't what you signed on for and you're getting frustrated. Second, start looking for a job that's a better fit, in case manglement can't or won't fix it.

The title of this post is "Taken for Stupid". I don't think this is an accurate description. It is more like your company discriminate against you on the basis of your gender (based on the description of your post).

The tittle needs to be changed, it doesn't reflect anything related to the text.

How exactly were you aware of the fact different questions were asked?

It seems all you can do is starting to look for better job offers.
Unless you can prove without a shadow of a doubt that your performance is better than some/most of them. Then you hypothetically maybe could argue that it was discrimination based on your gender, that, in itself, might never achieve anything in court.
Unless you have a written email where they express something like "I don't want to promote her, she's a woman", then it's a slam dunk.

Yeah, as a woman in tech who that has also happened to - it's hard to prove but easy to leave and find something better.
